# Automate editable PDF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, pdf-generation

I am working on an application that has a requirement for me to create a document, populated with data captured in my WPF application, for attaching to an email and sending to insurance company.

My client has been performing this by sending an editable PDF document to clients then proof reading upon receipt of completed form and manually attaching to email.

I initially thought of creating a word document laid out same format as existing and automating word using find/replace on placeholders such as  etc...

However it would be great if I could populate the existing PDF docs wouldn't it.... Anyone know if possible?

Thanks.

Comment: There are APIs for editing PDF files if that's what you are asking. One is iTextSharp which is a port of Java's iText.

Comment: In pdfs you actually would use form fields as place holders. While otherwise replacing text in the content stream is not completely impossible, it is very fickle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PDFsharp/MigraDoc to edit pdf-files. Parsing the existing document and inserting text/images is simple enough, but I don't know if there is any support for actual placeholders.

EDIT: Found this approach, using iTextSharp and form fields: [Using itextsharp (or any c# pdf library), how to open a PDF, replace some text, and save it again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221366/using-itextsharp-or-any-c-sharp-pdf-library-how-to-open-a-pdf-replace-some-t)

Comment: Thanks for responses. Instead of place holders, would it be easier if I could rename the fields in existing forms to sensible names then search for these fields and populate with data?

Comment: If the above is more feasible, what software would be required for me to edit existing PDF form for the field renaming exercise?

Comment: Cheers Jesper, 101% helped!